# XCODE: Adjusting UIImageView Size from NIB for iPhone 5 Devices

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uiimageview

I am trying to adjust the size of a background static `UIImageView` (from `Nib` file) for `iPhone5` users.  Unfortunately, the following code does not seem to make any difference on the background view's size.

Does anyone know why?  Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

**ViewController.m:**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    device = appDelegate.deviceType;
    NSLog(@"The device platform is: %@", device);
    if ([[device substringToIndex:8] caseInsensitiveCompare: @"iPhone 5"] == NSOrderedSame) {
        [background sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(320, 504)];
    }
    else {
        [background sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(320, 416)];
    }
...
//Note: 'background' is declared in `ViewController.h` as, `IBOutlet` `UIImageView` *background, and is linked to the image view in ViewController_iPhone.xib
```

Comment: I would discourage you from ever hard coding dimensions like `416` and `504` in your code. What if you later embed in a navigation controller? Or a tab controller? Or both? Or hide the status bar? Or Apple releases a 4.5" device? Etc. You shouldn't have to change the code of your view controller based upon how that view controller is being used (except maybe something radical like iPad v iPhone).

Comment: Or better yet, set the `autosizing` mask and don't change the frame programmatically at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few thoughts:

1. As demosten and shabzco suggested, I wouldn't use a device name/description to determine coordinates (if nothing else, what about the iPhone 6, etc.);
2. If you're going to set the `frame` programmatically, I would suggest setting the `background.frame` property based upon the view controller's view's `bounds` rather than hard coding the size of the image view. That way, the background is adjusted to the appropriate size of the view controller's view, not only regardless of device, but also regardless if that view controller is, at a later date, embedded as a child view controller of another container controller, etc. (E.g., what if you put your view in a navigation controller and tab bar controller, your own custom container controller, etc.). Also, don't make assumptions about the size of the status bar or other graphical elements. Let iOS figure all of this out for you with simply:

   ```
   background.frame = self.view.bounds;
   ```
3. Or better yet, if you've added the background image view to the NIB itself, set the autosizing mask and don't change the `frame` programmatically at all. If you have autolayout turned off, just set the autosizing properties of your image view like so:

   [image: auto sizing]

Bottom line, if you can, avoid explicit device name references in your code and avoid hard coded coordinates. To have hardcoded dimensions in your code will just make your app more fragile, susceptible to problems with new devices, new versions of iOS, embedding your view controller in additional container controllers, etc., and limits the reuse opportunities for your code.

Comment: I like what you are suggesting @Rob, and would like to make it the accepted answer.  However, when I edit my height to be '504' and set the autosizing properties like you suggest above for the UIImageView, the image is still pushed underneath my bottom toolbar  when running on the simulator/iphone4.  How can I ensure it does not get pushed below the toolbar or a potential future tabbar?

Comment: @JRoss feel free to meet me in chat so we can take this out of comments: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22021/chat-with-jross-re-nibs

Answer (score 2):

Here's a better way to check between iPhone 5 and previous sized devices

```
if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
{
    CGSize result = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;
    if(result.height == 480)
    {
        [background sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(320, 416)];
    }
    if(result.height == 568)
    {
        [background sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(320, 504)];
    }
}
```

Comment: Upped as a useful answer.
@shabzco That may be a better way, but it doesn't help adjust my image's size...  Do you know why?

Answer (score 1):

`sizeThatFits` does not change size. You should modify `background.frame`. Something like:

```
background.frame = CGRectMake(background.frame.origin.x, background.frame.origin.y, 320, 416);
```

and

```
background.frame = CGRectMake(background.frame.origin.x, background.frame.origin.y, 320, 504);
```

Also make sure your UIImageView does not have flexible width or height in Size inspector tab while editing your Nib file.